# Jsch - Opening multiple channels in a single session to SLES15 server is failing

Tags: ssh, jsch, openssh, sles

When executing commands by opening multiple channels in a single session to a SLES server is failing. This same code is working with all versions of SLES12, Centos7 and Centos8.

**JSCH version:** 0.1.55

**SSH Server Machine Details**
OS: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2
SSHD: OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d

**These are the errors in /var/log/messages:**
fatal: mm_answer_audit_server_key_free: buffer error: incomplete message
fatal: mm_request_receive: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: mm_request_send: write: Broken pipe

**This is the error in JSCH log:**
INFO:    Connecting to 10.75.32.47 port 22
INFO:    Connection established
INFO:    Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
INFO:    Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
INFO:    CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO:    CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO:    CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO:    SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO:    SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO:    kex: server: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
INFO:    kex: server: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
INFO:    kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
INFO:    kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
INFO:    kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO:    kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO:    kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO:    kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO:    kex: server:
INFO:    kex: server:
INFO:    kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO:    kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO:    kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO:    kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO:    kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO:    kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO:    kex: client: none
INFO:    kex: client: none
INFO:    kex: client:
INFO:    kex: client:
INFO:    kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
INFO:    kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
INFO:    SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
INFO:    expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
INFO:    ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARN:    Permanently added '10.75.32.47' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO:    SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO:    SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO:    SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO:    SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO:    Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO:    Next authentication method: publickey
INFO:    Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO:    Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO:    Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Waiting for all tasks to finish...
INFO:    Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Connection reset
INFO:    Disconnecting from 10.75.32.47 port 22

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class SSHTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession("userName", "hostAddress", 22);
            String command = "echo \"Hi\" && sleep 1";
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            config.put("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setPassword("david");
            session.setTimeout(60000);

            session.connect();

            ExecutorService channelsPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                channelsPool.execute(new TaskExecutor(command, session));
            }

            System.out.println("Waiting for all tasks to finish...");
            channelsPool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
            try {
                // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
                if (!channelsPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    channelsPool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                    // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                    if (!channelsPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                        System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("All tasks finished successfully");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
                channelsPool.shutdownNow();
                // Preserve interrupt status
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            session.disconnect();

            System.out.println("************************* Execution completed *************************");
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class TaskExecutor implements Runnable {

    private String command;
    private Session session;

    public TaskExecutor(String command, Session session) {
        this.command = command;
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void execute() throws JSchException, IOException {
        ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channelExec.setCommand(command);
        InputStream inputStream = channelExec.getInputStream();
        InputStream errorStream = channelExec.getErrStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = channelExec.getOutputStream();
        channelExec.connect();
        int exitCode = channelExec.getExitStatus();

        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> error = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader outputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream))) {
            boolean isDataLeftInStream = true;
            // Read data in output stream
            while (isDataLeftInStream) {
                String line = outputReader.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                    output.add(line);
                } else {
                    isDataLeftInStream = false;
                }
            }

            // Read data in error stream
            isDataLeftInStream = true;
            while (isDataLeftInStream) {
                String line = errorReader.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                    error.add(line);
                } else {
                    isDataLeftInStream = false;
                }
            }
        }
        
        channelExec.disconnect();

        System.out.println("Execution Result: \n\tExitCode=" + exitCode + "\n\tOutput=" + String.join("\n", output)
                + "\n\tError=" + String.join("\n", error));
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it's not a server-side problem? Did you verify anyhow that the server supports multiple channels at all? + Can you post [mcve]. I believe you code is unnecessarily complicated for the problem demonstration.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl With one channel per session its working fine. Only when multiple channels in same session are opened i'm facing this issue.   
I'm not sure whether the problem is with client side or server side. I tried some solutions related to server side configuration that i found on google but none solved the problem

Comment: @MartinPrikryl This is sample code with represents my actual use case which requires execution of multiple commands concurrently. I will try to give some simpler example if possible.

Comment: I see that you are using JSch Session from multiple threads. I'm quite sure that JSch is not thread safe – https://stackoverflow.com/q/38915200/850848

Comment: @MartinPrikryl But the same code is working with other operating systems. This is the first time we are seeing this issue when we wanted to support SLES15. Even the  sample code i added is working with other operating systems. I'm unable to figure out what's the problem with jsch and SLES15 combination.

Comment: You might have been just lucky that it works. That's common with concurrency issues. Afaik, **JSch is not thread safe**. Imo, your code is wrong, no matter that it may be working *sometimes*. Can you reproduce the multi-channel problem with a single-threaded code?