# JSch - Vertx.Future - Parallel process using same Session and ChannelSftp

Tags: parallel-processing, future, vert.x, jsch

I have a project that need to use Async programming (Promise-Future), and need to open do process Move, Remove and Upload files using JSch.

Here is the sample code (I make a similar behavior of my project)

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Future> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
      //Processing object, and complete Future
      Promise<String> promise = Promise.promise();
      //this is for sample test, it actually calling api service that took a long time 
      //to process and return the object, that's why I am using Future
      processFuture(promise.future());
    }
  }

  private static void processFuture(Future future){
    future.all(futureList).onComplete(res ->{
      if(res.succeeded()){
         Session session = null;
         ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
        try{
          Session session = connectSession();
          Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
          channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
          channelSftp.connect(2000);

          for(int j = 0 ; j < res.result().list().size(); j++){
            if(channelSftp.isConnected()){
                //Process Data with SFTP here
            }
          }
          channelSftp.disconnected();
          session.disconnected();
        }catch(Exception e){
          channelSftp.disconnected();
          session.disconnected();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private static void connectSession(){
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    try{
        session = jsch.getSession(userSetting, hostSetting, portSetting);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking","no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.setPassword(passwordSetting);
        session.connect();

    }catch(Exception e){
      throw e;
    }
    return session;
  }
}
```

The problem here is, when running `processFuture` which for processing data to sftp, it will keep opening same session, and it will gives a lot of error like session timeout, or error read sftp file and etc

Comment: See [If I use JSch from more than one thread, how should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38915200/850848).

Comment: I saw that post as well, but it will make it sync instead of async.

Comment: Sure. But it answers your question. You cannot use "same Session and ChannelSftp" in multiple threads.

Comment: I see, that's one of my biggest loophole in here. I am thinking a different approach, like put session as global variable and use it multiple times, until it broken and re-connect them again like that. That mean, my async way, need to be changed to somehow be sync, right?

Comment: Your approach is not really async. It just tries to reuse the same session in multiple threads. That's not possible. But you can open multiple sessions.

Comment: Actually it is because I am using Promise.Future which is asynchronous. The reason I made it like that is to skip waiting process on calling api service, and do the process after it complete -> processFuture (return the value from api)

Comment: That depends on the definition of "asynchronous". If you consider that asynchronous, then using multiple connections using `Promise.Future` will be asynchronous too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on references and info from @Martin, I decide to change my algorithm code and make it waiting result from async process before processing data with sftp.

The reason is because SFTP cannot open multiple same session with 100% identical configuration. It is a bit slow than before because I need to wait for service to do the process first, but it successfully process my data now.